# Como faço para enviar dados de uma JTable para o meu BD?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Possuo uma JTable preenchida e preciso armazenar os dados dela em uma tabela no meu banco de dados. Como faço isso? Somente conheço o caminho inverso(preencher uma tabela a partir do BD)
estou usando MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisará fazer o seguinte:

1. Conectar ao banco de dados usando as credenciais apropriadas e o driver JDBC correspondente.
2. Para cada linha da JTable  mapear o dado para uma um registro a ser gravado (pode ser um Array de Object onde cada Object recebe o valor da célula da JTable)
3. Gravar o registro usando PreparedStatment
4. Fechar a conexão com o banco de dados

That's all

Comment: eu quero fazer o oposto, pegar as linhas da minha jtable e armazenar no banco de dados

Comment: post corrigido !