# Como salvar a linha selecionada de uma JTable no BD?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho uma `JTable` que preenche do banco de dados, onde eu posso selecionar varias linhas ao mesmo tempo com o campo booleano que foi adicionado. Preciso que, quando clicar no botão "gravar" do meu `form` seja capturada as linhas que foram selecionadas na `JTable` para gravar no banco de dados.

[image: imagem]

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
int id= Integer.parseInt((String)txtCidadeAtendida.getValueAt(0, 0));
String cidade = (String) txtCidadeAtendida.getValueAt(0, 1);

pst.setString(3, (String)txtCidadeAtendida.getSelectedRow());
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, Daivid. Você já tem algum código pronto? Caso sim, edite sua pergunta e coloque-o para facilitar a resolução do seu problema.

Comment: Tenho este,      int id= Integer.parseInt((String)txtCidadeAtendida.getValueAt(0, 0));
        String cidade = (String) txtCidadeAtendida.getValueAt(0, 1);pst.setString(3, (String)txtCidadeAtendida.getSelectedRow());

Comment: Daivid, por favor, coloque o codigo que vc utilizou na pergunta, [editando-a](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/44807/edit). Se possivel coloque mais informações sobre o que está ocorrendo, se está aparecendo algum erro em algum sistema de console. E tambem aconselho a antes de fazer uma pergunta, procurar por outras iguais ([como essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44765)).

Comment: Outra coisa, vc consegue persistir 'qualquer coisa' no banco? Ou vc ainda não tem o banco configurado?

Comment: Consigo gravar normal no bd.